# Replace 16 digit identifier with new identifier

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to replace existing 16 digit identifier in a file with newly generated identifier defined in shell variable "NEW_IDENTIFIER".

```
SEARCH_PATTERN="g_ExistingMachineID"
NEW_IDENTIFIER="456EFABC-4567-546C-B4E2-DA2F45AE2CD3"

g_ExistingMachineID[] = _T( "{123ABCDE-1234-312C-B4E2-0E5F15BD1CA9}" )
```

**Desired Output**

```
g_ExistingMachineID[] = _T( "{456EFABC-4567-546C-B4E2-DA2F45AE2CD3}" )
```

I got the desired line using g_ExistingMachineID as search pattern but not able to get regular expression to replace 123ABCDE-3640-430C-B4E2-0E6F75AF6CA9 with value stored in NEW_IDENTIFIER.

I'm reading SED and trying few expression.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID doesn't contain any characters special to sed, plain `sed` with address + substitution should work:

```
sed -i~ "/$SEARCH_PATTERN/s/{.*}/{$NEW_IDENTIFIER}/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. It is working for me:-

```
 sed "/g_ExistingMachineID/s/{.*}/{$NEW_IDENTIFIER}/" yourfile.txt
```

Just tried with below:-

```
NEW_IDENTIFIER="456EFABC-4567-546C-B4E2-DA2F45AE2CD3"
echo 'g_ExistingMachineID[] = _T( "{123ABCDE-1234-312C-B4E2-0E5F15BD1CA9}" )' | sed "/g_ExistingMachineID/s/{.*}/{$NEW_IDENTIFIER}/"
```

Output:-

```
g_ExistingMachineID[] = _T( "{456EFABC-4567-546C-B4E2-DA2F45AE2CD3}" )
```